# CORS issue with 3 domains - what are the correct settings for CORS in this case?

Tags: node.js, nginx, cors

Ok, I've looked at a ton of questions on here and all around and can't seem to get this issue taken care of so if this is somehow a duplicate and I've missed something please point me in the right direction.

I've got a Node/Sails API server running at api.example.com, my js-sdk running from www.example.com and a client embedding the js-sdk at www.anotherdomain.com

**Both api. and www. have this for CORS in the NGINX config:**

```
location / {
 if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
    add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
    add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
    return 204;
 }
 if ($request_method = 'POST') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
 if ($request_method = 'GET') {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $http_origin;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
 }
}
```

**When I run a post to a valid endpoint from anotherdomain.com I get this error:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.example.com/users. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value ''. Origin 'www.anotherdomain.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: That would seem to indicate `$http_origin` is not getting set to the requesting origin as expected. Why not just set [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) to '*' instead? `add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*'`? I think the effect would be the same as setting it to `$http_origin` (assuming `$http_origin` is the requesting origin, and not the response origin)

Comment: @sideshowbarker - I had problems with that as well and read in other places that using  '*' with credentials: true also causes issues. In either case it is not working for whatever reason.

Comment: Ah yeah, doing '*' won’t work if you need to send credentials in the request.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind doing it in your application, you can directly configure CORS inside Sails by adding in config/cors.js :

```
allRoutes: true
```

See documentation [there](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/security/cors) and [there](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/configuration/sails-config-cors) for more details on the options